OnActionReceived is not invoked after RequestDecision is called In Unity ML-Agents
OnActionReceived is not invoked after RequestDecision is called In Unity ML-Agents
My Game is a turnbased game, so I must manually call the requestDecision Function.
I use Debug.Log() Function to test, and I find OnActionReceived is not invoked after RequestDecision is called
what should I do? thank you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
